# Does ReactiveUI RaiseAndSetIfChanged fire for List<T> Add, Delete, Modify?

Tags: c#, reactiveui

Will this fire

```
private List<TweetTileViewModel> _TweetTiles;
    public List<TweetTileViewModel> TweetTiles
    {
        get { return _TweetTiles; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _TweetTiles, value); }
    }
```

When I do:

```
TweetTiles.Add(new TweetTileViewModel(...)); or
TweetTiles.Remove(new TweetTileViewModel(...));
```

etc.

I suspect not, but am not sure how I should get this behavior.

I have a function, running on a background Task, that is returning tweets. Each time I get a new tweet I convert it to a TweetTileViewModel and want it to show in my UI listbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will this fire?

Nope, this will only fire when you *set* the list:

```
TweetTiles = new List<TweetTileViewModel>();
```

> I have a function, running on a background Task, that is returning tweets. Each time I get a new tweet I convert it to a TweetTileViewModel and want it to show in my UI listbox.

ReactiveUI has built-in support for this, via the `ReactiveList` class. Here's how you want to set it up - first, declare some properties:

```
ReactiveList<Tweet> Tweets { get; protected set; }
IReactiveDerivedList<TweetTileViewModel> TweetViewModels { get; protected set; }

ReactiveCommand LoadTweets { get; protected set; }
```

Then, in the constructor:

```
// Note: Only change this list on the UI thread!
Tweets = new ReactiveList<Tweet>();

// Now, TweetViewModels will "follow around" Tweets as you add and remove items
TweetViewModels = Tweets.CreateDerivedCollection(
    tweet => new TweetTileViewModel(tweet));

LoadTweets = new ReactiveCommand();

var newTweets = LoadTweets.RegisterAsyncTask(async _ => {
    // Loads the latest tweets
    return LoadTweetsAsync();
});

newTweets.Subscribe(newTweets => {
    // Add in the new tweets we downloaded. This is guaranteed by
    // ReactiveCommand to be on the UI thread
    Tweets.AddRange(newTweets);
});
```

**Update:** Fixed type error. To use a method that only sends a callback, use an AsyncSubject:

```
public IObservable<List<Tweet>> GetTweetsObservable(this TwitterClient This)
{
    var ret = new AsyncSubject<List<Tweet>>();

    try {
        This.GetTweetsWithCallback(tweets => {
            ret.OnNext(tweets);
            ret.OnCompleted();
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ret.OnError(ex);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Now, you can change `RegisterAsyncTask` to just `RegisterAsync` and you're good to go!

Comment: The Tweets.CreateDerivedCollection call gives me a cannot implicitly convert to IReactiveDerivedList<TweetTileViewModel>. Should I be using a different overload or just using an as?  One other thing. The api I am using to get tweets is using a callback, so the "LoadTweets" doesn't return.  Is there a way to do the Sub on the callback instead? Thanks

Comment: Wow...it is so close. I am only getting 1 update in the subscribe. The only diff between my code is that the return is 1 tweet instead of list of tweets. The first tweet the api returns calls the Subscribe onNext action, but subsequent tweets do not.
    StreamTweetsCommand = new ReactiveCommand();
            var newTweets = StreamTweetsCommand.RegisterAsync(p => twitterApi.GetTweetsObservable(SearchText));
            newTweets.Subscribe(x => {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Subscribe called to add {0}", x));
                Tweets.Add(x);
            });